# Update a nested object while maintaining the rest the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm starting with redux, and I want to do the following modification to my 
state:

From this:

```
state = {
  loaded: true,
  fetching false,
  byId: {
    "employeeID1": {
      id: "employeeID1",
      name: "Steve"
     },
    "employeeID2": {
      id: "employeeID2",
      name: "Susan"
     }
  }
}
```

To this:

```
{
  loaded: true,
  fetching false,
  byId: {
    "employeeID1": {
      id: "employeeID1",
      name: "Steve",
      data: data  // <---- add a new property

     },
    "employeeID2": {
      id: "employeeID2",
      name: "Susan"
     }
  }
}
```

This `const modifEmployee = {...state.byId["employeeID1"], data: data}` will give me the modified employee with the data.

But, how can I add the modified employee in byId while mantaining the others unchanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this using spread syntax:

```
{
  ...state,
  byId: {
    ...state.byId,
    employeeID1: { ...state.byId.employeeID1, data }
  }
}
```

If `"employeeID1"` value is a fetched from a variable `employeeId`, then you could use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
{
  ...state,
  byId: {
    ...state.byId,
    [employeeId]: { ...state.byId[employeeId], data }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, the second example works perfect in my case. If I've understood correctly, I need to use the spread operator on every "level"

Comment: @Ana you're welcome. Also, forgot to mention this. You don't need to do `data: data` if the variable name and the property name you're adding are the same. That's why just adding `data` works here. [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)